Edit host file in android emulator not working
In my mac book i edited the host file added `12.34.45.54  demo.test.com` after changing the host file it working perfectly in `ios simulator` but its not working in `android emulator .`

Here i have followed below step

 1. Step -1 `/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -writable-system
    -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel4` -> open it in writable mode
 2.Step -2 `adb root`
 3.Step -3  `adb remount` 
 4.Step -4 `adb pull /system/etc/hosts`
 5. step -5 edited the host file
 6. Step -6 adb push ./hosts /system/etc/hosts 

    here  am getting below error
    can't create hosts: Read-only file system

